# Highlight polygons that share a side/edge

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, intersection

How do I create a... *---I don't know; `list, dict`* of all the polygons, in a GeoDataFrame, that share a side/edge. The polygons will intersect but never cross.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

polys = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0), (2,0), (2, 1.5), (2,2), (0,2)]),
                     Polygon([(0,2), (2,2), (2,4), (0,4)]),
                     Polygon([(2,0), (5,0), (5,1.5), (2,1.5)]),
                     Polygon([(3,3), (5,3), (5,5), (3,5)])])

fp = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys, 'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                      'grnd': [25, 25, 25, 25],
                      'rf': [29, 35, 26, 31]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
fp.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.3, cmap='tab10', edgecolor='k',)
fp.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(text=x['name'], xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], ha='center'), axis=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```py
for i, row in fp.iterrows():
    oring = list(row.geometry.exterior.coords)#, row['ground_height']
    if row.geometry.exterior.is_ccw == False:
        #-- to get proper orientation of the normals
        oring.reverse() 
    for (j, v) in enumerate(oring[:-1]):
        print(oring[j][0], oring[j][1], oring[j+1][0], oring[j+1][1], row['name'])
```

Expected result:

```py
0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 a
2.0 0.0 2.0 1.5 a c
2.0 1.5 2.0 2.0 a 
2.0 2.0 0.0 2.0 a b
0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 a
0.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 b a
2.0 2.0 2.0 4.0 b 
2.0 4.0 0.0 4.0 b
0.0 4.0 0.0 2.0 b... and so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the expected result again, I would first create a series that includes all of the line segments and then check if each line segment both touches the polygon and that the length of intersection is greater than 0:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

polys = gpd.GeoSeries([
    Polygon([(0,0), (2,0), (2, 1.5), (2,2), (0,2)]),
    Polygon([(0,2), (2,2), (2,4), (0,4)]),
    Polygon([(2,0), (5,0), (5,1.5), (2,1.5)]),
    Polygon([(3,3), (5,3), (5,5), (3,5)])
])

fp = gpd.GeoDataFrame({
    'geometry': polys, 
    'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'grnd': [25, 25, 25, 25],
    'rf': [29, 35, 26, 31]
})

# Create series of all the line segments
lines = fp.geometry.apply(lambda x: list(map(
    LineString, 
    zip(x.boundary.coords[:-1], x.boundary.coords[1:]))
)).explode()

result = {
    str(line): list(fp.loc[
        (fp.geometry.touches(line)) # line touches the polygon
        & (fp.geometry.intersection(line).length > 0), # And the intersection is more than just a point
        'name'
    ].values)
    for line in lines
}
```

output:

```
{'LINESTRING (0 0, 2 0)': ['a'],
 'LINESTRING (2 0, 2 1.5)': ['a', 'c'],
 'LINESTRING (2 1.5, 2 2)': ['a'],
 'LINESTRING (2 2, 0 2)': ['a', 'b'],
 'LINESTRING (0 2, 0 0)': ['a'],
 'LINESTRING (0 2, 2 2)': ['a', 'b'],
 'LINESTRING (2 2, 2 4)': ['b'],
 'LINESTRING (2 4, 0 4)': ['b'],
 'LINESTRING (0 4, 0 2)': ['b'],
 'LINESTRING (2 0, 5 0)': ['c'],
 'LINESTRING (5 0, 5 1.5)': ['c'],
 'LINESTRING (5 1.5, 2 1.5)': ['c'],
 'LINESTRING (2 1.5, 2 0)': ['a', 'c'],
 'LINESTRING (3 3, 5 3)': ['d'],
 'LINESTRING (5 3, 5 5)': ['d'],
 'LINESTRING (5 5, 3 5)': ['d'],
 'LINESTRING (3 5, 3 3)': ['d']}
```

Comment: Your `result = {...}` one-liners are pretty slick. Thank you. Are you getting a `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in intersection`? How would I add a second parameter like the `grnd` and `rf` column?

Comment: I think the `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in intersection` warnings might be due to [this issue](https://github.com/shapely/shapely/pull/1728) in GEOS.  [See also this issue](https://github.com/shapely/shapely/issues/1345).  Installing GEOS>=3.12 may fix this issue (Haven't tested).

Comment: There are many ways you could add `grnd` and `rf` to the result.  One approach could be writing it as a json file and adding it to the dict like this:
```
result = {
    str(line): json.loads(fp.loc[
        (fp.geometry.touches(line)) # line touches the polygon
        & (fp.geometry.intersection(line).length > 0), # And the intersection is more than just a point
        ['name', 'grnd', 'rf']
    ].to_json(orient='records'))
    for line in lines
}
```
You will need to `import json` to use `json.loads`

Comment: you are being extremely generous and patient with me. Thank you. How would I account for `MultiPolygons`? If I need to ask a separate question please advise.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75814822/3669465) help you?

Comment: I added an edit that can handle multipolygons.  It gets a bit wonky with all the packing and unpacking, but it shoudl work.

Comment: No @Zach Flanders. I opened a different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75837837/dictionary-of-polygon-sides-edges-including-multipolygons). You can remove your edit and answer at the other post please.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`geopandas.GeoSeries.touches`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.touches.html)?

You could do something like the following:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

polys = gpd.GeoSeries([
    Polygon([(0,0), (2,0), (2, 1.5), (2,2), (0,2)]),
    Polygon([(0,2), (2,2), (2,4), (0,4)]),
    Polygon([(2,0), (5,0), (5,1.5), (2,1.5)]),
    Polygon([(3,3), (5,3), (5,5), (3,5)])
])

fp = gpd.GeoDataFrame({
    'geometry': polys, 
    'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'grnd': [25, 25, 25, 25],
    'rf': [29, 35, 26, 31]
})

result = {
    row['name']: {
        'touching polygons': list(fp.loc[fp.geometry.touches(row.geometry), 'name'].values)
    }
    for i, row in fp.iterrows()
}
```

output:

```
{
    'a': {'touching polygons': ['b', 'c']}, 
    'b': {'touching polygons': ['a']}, 
    'c': {'touching polygons': ['a']}, 
    'd': {'touching polygons': []}
}
```

Comment: No. Per side/edge please. Like the expected result.  Thumbs-up for the 'result = { … }' one liner.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `Expected result`, I can say that, no spatial predicate available to operate and get that kind of result. `Intersects` or `touches` between 2 geometries will get some false-positive results.

Here I implement a simple check, `same_lineQ(x1y1, x2y2)`, as a procedure to use in place where the missing spatial op is needed.

```
# PART 1
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString, Point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

polys = gpd.GeoSeries([
    Polygon([(0,0), (2,0), (2, 1.5), (2,2), (0,2)]),
    Polygon([(0,2), (2,2), (2,4), (0,4)]),
    Polygon([(2,0), (5,0), (5,1.5), (2,1.5)]),
    Polygon([(3,3), (5,3), (5,5), (3,5)])
])

fp = gpd.GeoDataFrame({
    'geometry': polys, 
    'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'grnd': [25, 25, 25, 25],
    'rf': [29, 35, 26, 31]
})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5/2, 5/2))
fp.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.3, cmap='tab10', edgecolor='k',)
fp.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(text=x['name'], xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], ha='center'), axis=1)

# Part 2
# Collect all the line segments from all polygons
def get_all_xy0xy1(p1, attrib="none"):
    """
    p1: a Polygon object, has single `exterior`
    returns: list of [[x0,y0],[x1,y1]] ready for LineString creation
    eg.: LineString([(0, 0), (9, 9)])
    """
    xy0_xy1_list = []
    attribs = []
    for ix,xy in enumerate(zip(p1.exterior.xy[0], p1.exterior.xy[1])):
        # 3 or more items
        #print(ix,xy)  #either x, or y separately
        if ix>0:
            #print([prev, xy]) #list of x,y; from-to
            xy0_xy1_list.append([prev, xy])
            attribs.append(attrib)
        prev = xy
    return xy0_xy1_list, attribs

# Line segments are collected in `all_line_segs`
all_line_segs = []
names = []
for ix, row in fp.iterrows():
    name = row['name']
    geom = row.geometry
    all_line_segs += get_all_xy0xy1(geom, name)[0]
    names += get_all_xy0xy1(geom, name)[1]

# Create a dataframe using the line segments
line_segs = pd.DataFrame({
    'xy1_xy2': all_line_segs, 
    'name': names
})

# Part 3
def same_lineQ(x1y1, x2y2):
    """
    Input: x1y1, x2y2; two list of (x,y).
    Returns:
     True if they represent the same LineString
       ignoring the direction
     else returns False.
    """
    return (x1y1[0] in x2y2) and (x1y1[1] in x2y2)

for ir, irow in line_segs.iterrows():
    iname = irow['name']
    ixys = irow['xy1_xy2']
    targets = set()
    for kr, krow in line_segs.iterrows():
        if ir != kr:
            kname = krow['name']
            if iname != kname:
                kxys = krow['xy1_xy2']

                if same_lineQ(ixys, kxys)==True:
                    #print(ixys, kxys, same_lineQ(ixys, kxys))
                    targets.update(kname)

        else:
            pass
    if len(targets)==0:
        print(ixys[0][0],ixys[0][1], ixys[1][0],ixys[1][1], iname)
    else:    
        print(ixys[0][0],ixys[0][1], ixys[1][0],ixys[1][1], iname, targets.pop())
```

Output:

```
0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 a
2.0 0.0 2.0 1.5 a c
2.0 1.5 2.0 2.0 a
2.0 2.0 0.0 2.0 a b
0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 a
0.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 b a
2.0 2.0 2.0 4.0 b
2.0 4.0 0.0 4.0 b
0.0 4.0 0.0 2.0 b
2.0 0.0 5.0 0.0 c
5.0 0.0 5.0 1.5 c
5.0 1.5 2.0 1.5 c
2.0 1.5 2.0 0.0 c a
3.0 3.0 5.0 3.0 d
5.0 3.0 5.0 5.0 d
5.0 5.0 3.0 5.0 d
3.0 5.0 3.0 3.0 d
```

**Edit**

If the geodataframe is more complex, for example, some polygons have holes, or some rows have MultiPolygon instead of Polygon, The code above won't work. It only work with geodataframe that have polygons without holes only.

So what to do in such situation?

One approach is to explode the rows that do not have simple polygon, i.e. have polygon with holes or multipolygon, and get a resulting geodataframe that have all simple polygons.

Take this modified geodataframe as an example:

[image: modified_df]

(Note `e` is MultiPolygon of 2 Polygons, one of it has single hole. And `f` is simple Polygon.)

If it is used with the code above, the output will be:

```
0.0 0.0 2.0 0.0 a
2.0 0.0 2.0 1.5 a c
2.0 1.5 2.0 2.0 a
2.0 2.0 0.0 2.0 a b
0.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 a
0.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 b a
2.0 2.0 2.0 4.0 b
2.0 4.0 0.0 4.0 b
0.0 4.0 0.0 2.0 b
2.0 0.0 5.0 0.0 c
5.0 0.0 5.0 1.5 c
5.0 1.5 2.0 1.5 c
2.0 1.5 2.0 0.0 c a
3.0 3.0 5.0 3.0 d
5.0 3.0 5.0 5.0 d e
5.0 5.0 3.0 5.0 d
3.0 5.0 3.0 3.0 d
6.5 0.0 7.5 0.0 f
7.5 0.0 7.5 1.5 f
7.5 1.5 6.5 1.5 f e
6.5 1.5 6.5 0.0 f
6.0 1.0 8.0 1.0 e
8.0 1.0 8.0 3.0 e
8.0 3.0 6.0 3.0 e
6.0 3.0 6.0 1.0 e
5.0 3.0 8.0 3.0 e
8.0 3.0 8.0 5.0 e
8.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 e
5.0 5.0 5.0 3.0 e d
6.5 2.5 7.5 2.5 e
7.5 2.5 7.5 1.5 e
7.5 1.5 6.5 1.5 e f
6.5 1.5 6.5 2.5 e
```

Comment: Thank you. I am grateful for your time and attention. Right now I'm going with @Zach Flanders because his one-liners are pretty slick.

Comment: @arkriger But how about `the exact format` of the output. Does that count? However, its all up to you. My code aims at finding solution first without focusing the programming style.

Comment: @arkriger ... and in the current form, it can be modified to bypass the using of `dataframe` libraries easily.

Comment: The result is as expected. Thank you. Consensus recommends [exhaust all other options before iterating a df (gdf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas). I'm not very knowledgeable; so generally when I find a solution that does not iterate: I go with that.

Comment: @arkriger I see.  Good programmers try to get correct result first, then, optimize the coding later.

Comment: @arkriger The proper way to thank is a vote_up.

Comment: @arkriger I edited my answer to give you some ideas that may be useful to your new question.